# php errors (Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in

Tags: php, mysql

```
$sorgu=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  users WHERE UserName='$userName' AND  Password='$password'"); 
if( mysql_affected_rows() )
{
    **$row=mysql_fetch_array($sorgu);**            /// this line is erorr
    if(in_array($row["UserID"],$_SESSION["id_array"]))
    {
        echo "session is already open";
    }


    else
    {

        $array=array(
            "id" => $row["UserID"],
            "userName" => $row["UserName"],
            "email" => $row["Email"],
            "admin" => $row["admin"],
        );


        $_SESSION["login"]=true;

        $_SESSION["array"][$row["UserID"]] = $array;

        $_SESSION["id_array"][]=$row["UserID"];

        $_SESSION["userid"] = $row["UserID"];

        header("Location: index.php");
```

Comment: it means $sorgu is not what you think it is, what could be the reason, the database is not connected/

Comment: Add the code that set the value of "$sorgu", it seems like it is not a valid mysql resource.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to [**SQL injection**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks, and you are using the **deprecated** `mysql` extension. Please consider looking into [**PDO**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [**mysqli**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) and **use parameterized queries**! Also, it appears you're storing passwords in plaintext---[you should **hash** and **salt** your passwords before storing them](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php).

Answer (score -1):

Use "mysql_num_rows($sorgu) > 0" instead of mysql_affected_rows() on line 2

mysql_affected_rows() is intended to check UPDATEs and INSERTs, not SELECTs.

Comment: sorry I changed but the problem continues